# Watson Visual Recognition API

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to use the Watson Visual Recognition API as an OCR component, however while it is doing a good job on the computerized text, I want to expand it more to recognize "Nicely-handwritten" text.

Is it possible to use the custom classifiers to train the API? and if yes and someone did try it already, is it effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, the text recognition part of Watson Visual Recognition cannot be trained by users.

The custom classifier learning functions cannot be used effectively for text recognition.  They are designed for classifying a wide array of photographic-style images of scenes, activities, objects, animal types, etc.  Text reco is a pretty different problem.  In some limited situations, you could train a classifier to do text-related tasks, like to tell the difference between signs (such as Yield vs. Stop) or icons (like logos) for example but it would not be "reading" the text - it would be discriminating based on the overall appearance of the image - including color, shapes, textures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The text recognition part of WVR is BETA at this time ([as mentioned in documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/tutorials.shtml#text)). It can't be trained as far as I am aware.